# insert an array in database laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

Please i need help, I want to insert a table whose the first lines is fixed 
and the others is added by jQuery.

My table is at the center of a form.

My problem is at the level of the `foreach` that I want to use to register my values ​​in my db i think my error is that i don't know how to use `foreach` in controller!!!

My view:

```
<table class="mws-table" id="tableFeesCompSheet">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{Lang::get('labels.fees_comp_sheet_labels.Max_interval_amount')}}</th>
      <th>{{Lang::get('labels.fees_comp_sheet_labels.Law5_fixed_amount')}}</th>
      <th>{{Lang::get('labels.fees_comp_sheet_labels.Law5_rate')}}</th>
      <th>{{Lang::get('labels.fees_comp_sheet_labels.Law5_min_amount')}}</th>
      <th>{{Lang::get('labels.fees_comp_sheet_labels.Law5_max_amount')}}</th>
      <th>{{Lang::get('labels.fees_comp_sheet_labels.Law5_grace_amount')}}</th>
      <th class="nosort">{{Lang::get('labels.action')}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="myTableRow">
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="max_interval_amount[]" class="amount no-padding" value="{{Input::get('max_interval_amount')}}" required="" data-parsley-type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="law5_fixed_amount" name="law5_fixed_amount[]" class="amount no-padding" value="{{Input::get('law5_fixed_amount')}}" required="" data-parsley-type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="law5_rate" name="law5_rate[]" class="amount no-padding" value="{{Input::get('law5_rate')}}" required="" data-parsley-type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="law5_min_amount" name="law5_min_amount[]" class="amount no-padding" value="{{Input::get('law5_min_amount')}}" required="" data-parsley-type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="law5_max_amount" name="law5_max_amount[]" class="amount no-padding" value="{{Input::get('law5_max_amount')}}" required="" data-parsley-type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="law5_grace_amount" name="law5_grace_amount[]" class="amount no-padding" value="{{Input::get('law5_grace_amount')}}" required="" data-parsley-type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="add" class="btn" data-original-title="Ajouter une ligne">
          <i class="icon-edit"></i>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery code to add a new row in the array:

```
function deleteRecord(ele) {
    $(ele.parentNode.parentNode).remove();
}
$("#delete" ).click(function deleteRow() {
    // console.log('walid');
    //  $("tr:has(input:checked)").remove();
});

$('#send').click(function(){
    $.each($('.field'), function() {
        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', $(this).attr('name'))
            .attr('value', $(this).val())
            .appendTo('#add_fees_rules');
    }
);

$( "#add_fees_rules" ).submit();
return false;
});
```

and my controller :

```
$fees_rules_comp_sheet= input::all();

foreach ($fees_rules_comp_sheet as $fees_comp_sheet) {

    $fees_comp_sheet = new FeesCompSheet();
    $fees_comp_sheet->fees_comp_sheet_id = $this->getFeesCompSheetId();
    $fees_comp_sheet->max_interval_amount = Input::get('max_interval_amount');
    $fees_comp_sheet->law5_fixed_amount = Input::get('law5_fixed_amount');
    $fees_comp_sheet->law5_rate = Input::get('law5_rate');
    $fees_comp_sheet->law5_min_amount = Input::get('law5_min_amount');
    $fees_comp_sheet->law5_max_amount = Input::get('law5_max_amount');
    $fees_comp_sheet->law5_grace_amount = Input::get('law5_grace_amount');
    $fees_comp_sheet->save();
```

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some potential problems based on your provided information. I can't say exactly. Because, you haven't provided detail error message.

First thing  first, check your model `FeesCompSheet` file. Your error may occurs **MassAssignmentException** if you don't have the following line of code.

```
  protected $fillable = ['fees_comp_sheet_id','max_interval_amount',
                         'law5_fixed_amount','law5_rate','law5_min_amount',
                         'law5_max_amount','law5_grace_amount'];
```

Second, please remove `[]` from all input type `name` attribute.

e.g

```
<input type="text" id="law5_rate" name="law5_rate" class="amount no-padding" value="{{Input::get('law5_rate')}}" required="" data-parsley-type="number">
```

Correct me if I wrong. `Input::get('law5_rate');` meaning, `name` attribute from your input type. Not `id` attribute.

Comment: yes it's a name atribute of my imput, and the error that i have is:
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
HELP
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array